# Simple Sequential model error : You must compile your model before using it

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, sequential

> This error seems to go if i remove the Flatten() layer.

I am trying to use my model but it is giving this runtime error :
You must compile your model before using it.

I don't understand what is wrong, I've tried using lesser Dense layers but it is not working.

Can someone help me with this? PLZ explain with code.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten



train_directory = 'D:\D_data\Rock_Paper_Scissors\Train'
training_datgagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
training_generator = training_datgagen.flow_from_directory(
train_directory,
target_size = (150,150),
class_mode = 'categorical')

validation_directory = 'D:\D_data\Rock_Paper_Scissors\Test'
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1./255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
validation_directory,
target_size = (150,150),
class_mode = 'categorical'
)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape = (22500,)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'])


model.fit_generator(training_generator,epochs = 15,validation_data = validation_generator,verbose =1)
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\Ankit\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 33, in <module>
model.fit_generator(training_generator,epochs = 15,validation_data = validation_generator,verbose =1)

File "C:\Users\Ankit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ankit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1732, in fit_generator
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)

File "C:\Users\Ankit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 42, in fit_generator
model._make_train_function()

File "C:\Users\Ankit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 303, in _make_train_function
raise RuntimeError('You must compile your model before using it.')

RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.
```

Comment: In which line, do you get the error? It seems you're compiling.

Comment: I have added the error in the question, plz see the question again.

Comment: the input shape should be specified in the first layer (which is Flatten, not Dense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because your network is inconsistent, the `input_shape` parameter should be given to the first layer in your network, but you are giving it to the second layer.

The solution is simple, put the right `input_shape` to your `Flatten` layer.